# strtok for GPS parsing, cannot identify string

Tags: c, parsing, arduino, gps

I am not the best programmer, but I have researched and tried different angles to parsing a GPS string.

I am currently working on a University project where my team and I are building the autonomous section of a Robotic Yard Weeder. I am in charge of creating a custom D-GPS. I cannot use TinyGPS because we are not allowed to use Arduino software, so I have to work with 'C'.

We don't have our microcontroller yet, so I am still using Arduino software, just trying to do it without TinyGPS.

This was all the setup given by TinyGPS:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define ARDUINO_GPS_RX 9 // Arduino RX pin connected to GPS TX
#define ARDUINO_GPS_TX 8 // Arduino TX pin connected to GPS RX
#define GPS_BAUD_RATE 9600 // The GPS Shield module defaults to 9600 baud
// Create a SoftwareSerial object called gps:
SoftwareSerial gpsPort(ARDUINO_GPS_TX, ARDUINO_GPS_RX);

// We'll also define a more descriptive moniker for the Serial Monitor port.
// This is the hardware serial port on pins 0/1.
#define SerialMonitor Serial

#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

Here is where I try to parse:

```
const char string[] = gpsPort.read();
const char delimiters[] = "$GPRMC,";
char *cp, *tokentime, *tokenA, *tokenlat, *tokenlng, *tokenfixed, *tokensat, *tokendil, *tokenalt, *tokengeoid, *tokenempty, *tokenchecksum;

void setup() 
{
  gpsPort.begin(GPS_BAUD_RATE);
  SerialMonitor.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
 if (gpsPort.available()) // If GPS data is available
    //SerialMonitor.write(gpsPort.read()); // Read it and print to SerialMonitor

  if (SerialMonitor.available()) // If SerialMonitor data is available
    gpsPort.write(SerialMonitor.read()); // Read it and send to GPS

cp = strdupa (string);                /* Make writable copy.  */
tokensentence = strtok (cp, delimiters); /*gets the first sentence to parse*/
 tokentime = strtok (NULL, delimiters);      /* token => 123519 "time taken at 12 o clock 35 min 19 sec" */
tokenA = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "A"ignore */
tokenlat = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token =>  4807.038,N     "Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N" */
tokenlng = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 01131.000,E "Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E" */
tokenfixed = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 1 "Fix quality: 0 = invalid" */
tokensat = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 08 "Number of satellites being tracked" */
tokendil = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 0.9 "Horizontal dilution of position" */
tokenalt = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 545.4,M "Altitude, Meters, above mean sea level" */
tokengeoid = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => 46.9,M "Height of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84 ellipsoid */
tokenempty = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => empty field */
tokenchecksum = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => *47 "the checksum data, always begins with *" */

SerialMonitor.print("Lat: "); SerialMonitor.println(tokenlat);
SerialMonitor.print("Lng: "); SerialMonitor.println(tokenlng);

}
```

The issue that I am having is that the 'initializer fails to determine the size of the string'. All the examples I have seen have a set defined string, but I don't know how to parse using strtok with 'live' data (if that is the best way to call it). I have tried using 'serial.read' by itself instead of 'gpsPort.available', but had no luck.

Just some background information, this code:

```
void setup() 
{
  SerialMonitor.begin(9600); // Initialize the serial monitor port at 9600 baud
  gpsPort.begin(GPS_BAUD_RATE); // The GPS module's default baud is 9600
}

void loop() 
{
  if (gpsPort.available()) // If GPS data is available
    SerialMonitor.write(gpsPort.read()); // Send it to the serial monitor
  if (SerialMonitor.available()) // If data is sent to the serial monitor
    gpsPort.write(SerialMonitor.read()); // send it to the GPS module
}
```

Gives out this set of strings:

```
$GPRMC,235316.000,A,4003.9040,N,10512.5792,W,0.09,144.75,141112,,*19
$GPGGA,235317.000,4003.9039,N,10512.5793,W,1,08,1.6,1577.9,M,-20.7,M,,0000*5F
$GPGSA,A,3,22,18,21,06,03,09,24,15,,,,,2.5,1.6,1.9*3E
```

I am ultimately trying to parse out the latitude and longitude.

Comment: This is a great question, which I will upvote, but I have trimmed out a lot of chat. Please try to avoid material like "I really have searched for ages" and "is this question okay" as that often features in questions without any effort or research, and you don't want to sound like them! `:-)`

Comment: Of interest: [GPS - NMEA sentence information](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/)

Comment: Did you notice that each example line has a different start, e.g. `$GPRMC`,`$GPGGA`, and `$GPGSA`. If you just Google that you will quickly find [GPS - NMEA sentence information](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) which give the details on each line type. Also without running this I see `const char delimiters[] = "$GPRMC,";` which looks very wrong as `$`,`G`,`P`,`R`,`M`,and `C` are not used as delimiters; I would expect something link `const char delimiters[] = ",";`

Answer (score 1):

First rule in programming is research potential existing solutions to exploit - so you can concentrate on your problem.

There is (at least) one open source C project that has solved this and has source code in a C library to consider - for free.

http://nmea.sourceforge.net/ 
has the features:

Features

- Analysis NMEA sentences and granting GPS data in C structures
- Generate NMEA sentences
- Supported sentences: GPGGA, GPGSA, GPGSV, GPRMC, GPVTG
- Multilevel architecture of algorithms
- Additional functions of geographical mathematics and work with navigation data

Comment: `First rule in programming is research potential existing solutions to exploit` you sound line a [Ferengi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferengi) with Rules of Acquisition.